# What should be the permissions/setup of www directory, if only purpose is to communicate with a desktop app through POST requests?

Tags: php, apache, security, permissions

I have simply two .php files on my Ubuntu Apache server, inside /var/www/html/

I use these .php files to ensure the client has proper licence, with MySQL queries.

I also have the secret key to the encrypted data between client and server, in one of these .php files. If storing the secret key in another directory and reading it from the .php is safer, I might need to do that too.

These .php files do no writing, they just receive POST requests, do SQL queries and return an encrypted answer.

What should my directory look like? Can I have root as the owner of these files or do I need to set www-data?

I've noticed that I can still do requests even if I set permissions to 0000 on the .php file, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: better to have www-data as the owner, as that's the account under which the webserver normally runs. Avoid using root as the owner for anything, unless it actually _needs_ to be. And 550 ought to be minimum needed permissions for the PHP files, enough to be read and executed by the owner and group. Surprised that 000 works, to be honest, it shouldn't AFAIK. Most people would probably recommended storing your secret key in another locked down folder which sits outside the webserver's structure (so the file can't accidentally be served directly over HTTP).

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the answer, I'll double check if 000 really works or not, and I'll look into having key outside of webserver!